# Orchard Record (Model is not valid )

Tags: c#, orchardcms

I'm getting this exception which i did ensured its not going to be thrown .

```
could not execute query
[ select TOP (1) customerre0_.Id as Id6_, customerre0_.SystemId as SystemId6_, customerre0_.CustomerGuid as Customer3_6_, customerre0_.UserName as UserName6_, customerre0_.Email as Email6_, customerre0_.CreatedDateTime as CreatedD6_6_, customerre0_.InstId as Institut7_6_, customerre0_.DistId as Distribu8_6_ from CustomerRecord customerre0_ where customerre0_.SystemId=@p0 ]
  Name:p1 - Value:2
[SQL: select TOP (1) customerre0_.Id as Id6_, customerre0_.SystemId as SystemId6_, customerre0_.CustomerGuid as Customer3_6_, customerre0_.UserName as UserName6_, customerre0_.Email as Email6_, customerre0_.CreatedDateTime as CreatedD6_6_, customerre0_.InstId as Institut7_6_, customerre0_.DistId as Distribu8_6_ from CustomerRecord customerre0_ where customerre0_.SystemId=@p0]'
```

Note I have my Model on `.Model` namespace and an Id . the table exist as well .

Any hints is really appreciated

Comment: What exactly is the error? I suggest you run the statement in SQL console to get the detailed error.

Comment: the exception is Model "CustomerRecord" Is Not valid

Comment: Hint: imho you are missing something as the query states `CustomerRecord` but Orchard tables are normally always prefixed by `Orchard_`.

Comment: You need to share more information. Can we see the model class, the migrations, the exception. I see you have a guid property on there, and I remember having a strange issue with mapping guids in Orchard's migrations that meant you had to explicitly set the `DbType` to guid like so: `.Column("CustomerGuid", DbType.Guid, column => column.NotNull().Unique())` But just a shot in the dark, more info!